# Не открывается окно по нажатию на клавишу? Pynput

Tags: python, pyqt, сигналы-слоты, qlabel, pynput

Есть приложение, в котором есть основное и дополнительное окно. 
Я создал экземпляр `QWidgets`, в него поместил `QLabel` с картинкой.
Картинок может быть несколько.

Нужно добавить чтобы при нажатии на клавишу один, у меня открывалось это окно и в дальнейшем повторное нажатие листало эти картинки, а по завершению условно списка с их именами, то это окно закрывалось в таком духе.

У меня есть код, при инициализации функции всё работает окно открывается, но когда пытаюсь её вызвать в функции `on_press()` всё зависает.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно исправить. Я могу ошибаться во многом, заранее извините.

````
import sys
import os
from os import listdir
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QByteArray, QBuffer, QIODevice, QTimer, QCoreApplication, QMetaObject
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
from pynput import keyboard
import threading
from PIL import Image as PImage


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()
        self.show()

        self.images = self.load_images("C:/Users/david/PycharmProjects/selenium/images/")
        print(self.images)

        self.imageViewer = QWidget()  # Инициализируем атрибут imageViewer
        self.imageViewer.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)

        self.show_image()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Desktop application")
        self.setGeometry(1920 - 800, 50, 800, 250)

        # Название
        label_name = QLabel("Название:", self)
        label_name.setGeometry(20, 20, 155, 20)
        label_name.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        label_name_text = QLabel("Название", self)
        label_name_text.setGeometry(180, 20, 135, 20)
        label_name_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # Стоимость
        label_cost = QLabel("Стоимость:", self)
        label_cost.setGeometry(20, 50, 155, 20)
        label_cost.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        label_cost_text = QLabel("Стоимость", self)
        label_cost_text.setGeometry(180, 50, 135, 20)
        label_cost_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # Размер
        label_size = QLabel("Размер:", self)
        label_size.setGeometry(20, 80, 155, 20)
        label_size.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        label_size_text = QLabel("Размер", self)
        label_size_text.setGeometry(180, 80, 135, 20)
        label_size_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # Комплектация
        label_equipment = QLabel("Комплектация:", self)
        label_equipment.setGeometry(20, 110, 155, 20)
        label_equipment.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        label_equipment_text = QLabel("Комплектация", self)
        label_equipment_text.setGeometry(180, 110, 135, 20)
        label_equipment_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # Причина
        label_reason = QLabel("Причина:", self)
        label_reason.setGeometry(20, 140, 155, 20)
        label_reason.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        label_reason_text = QLabel("Причина", self)
        label_reason_text.setGeometry(180, 140, 135, 20)
        label_reason_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # Причина комментария
        label_reason_comment = QLabel("Причина комментария:", self)
        label_reason_comment.setGeometry(20, 170, 155, 20)
        label_reason_comment.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        label_reason_comment_text = QLabel("Комментарий", self)
        label_reason_comment_text.setGeometry(180, 170, 135, 20)
        label_reason_comment_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # Количество картинок
        label_image_count = QLabel("Количество картинок:", self)
        label_image_count.setGeometry(20, 200, 155, 20)
        label_image_count.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        label_image_count_text = QLabel("5", self)
        label_image_count_text.setGeometry(180, 200, 135, 20)
        label_image_count_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # Бренд
        label_brand = QLabel("Бренд:", self)
        label_brand.setGeometry(400, 20, 130, 20)
        label_brand.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        label_brand_text = QLabel("Бренд", self)
        label_brand_text.setGeometry(540, 20, 135, 20)
        label_brand_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # Подозрительный
        label_suspicious = QLabel("Подозрительный:", self)
        label_suspicious.setGeometry(400, 50, 130, 20)
        label_suspicious.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        label_suspicious_text = QLabel("Нет", self)
        label_suspicious_text.setGeometry(540, 50, 135, 20)
        label_suspicious_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)

    def load_images(self, path):
        # return array of images
        loadedImages = []
        folder_path = path

        # Получаем список файлов в папке
        files = os.listdir(folder_path)

        # Выводим имена файлов
        for file in files:
            loadedImages.append(file)
        return loadedImages

    def show_image(self):
        # Не нужно создавать новый объект QWidget() здесь
        # self.imageViewer = QWidget()

        self.imageViewer.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)

        self.image_label = QLabel()
        self.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap(f"images/{self.images[0]}"))  # Выбирайте конкретное изображение

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()  # добавляем виджеты в макет
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.image_label)

        self.imageViewer.setLayout(self.main_layout)  # устанавливаем макет

        self.imageViewer.showMaximized()  # показываем imageViewer


def show(w):
    def get_key_name(key):
        if isinstance(key, keyboard.KeyCode):
            return key.char
        else:
            return str(key)

    def on_press(key):
        key_name = get_key_name(key)
        print(key_name)

        if key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('0'):
            if w.isVisible():
                w.hide()
            else:
                w.show()
        elif key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char("3"):
            w.show_image()
        # elif key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char("2"):
        #   w.prev_image()

    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet("""
    QLabel {
        color: #333;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
""")
w = MainWindow()
threading.Thread(target=show, args=(w,), daemon=True).start()
sys.exit(app.exec_())```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю для чего вам окно, которое создается в методе `init_ui()`,
но написано оно не красиво. Но это уже другой вопрос.

Используем прослушиватель *Pynput* и анализируем keycode, затем отправляем его с помощью сигнала в графический интерфейс, который в соответствии со своей собственной логикой добавляет в `QLabel` изображение.

Запускайте приложение и нажимайте клавиши  <kbd>0</kbd>,  <kbd>2</kbd> и <kbd>3</kbd>

```
import sys
# ? import os
from os import listdir
#from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener, KeyCode
# ? import threading
# ? from PIL import Image as PImage

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
                         

class KeyMonitor(QObject):
    charPressed = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.listener = Listener(on_release=self.on_release)

    def on_release(self, key):
        if key == KeyCode.from_char('0'):                               # ! '0'
            self.charPressed.emit('0')
        if key == KeyCode.from_char('2'):                               # ! '2'
            self.charPressed.emit('2')
        elif key == KeyCode.from_char('3'):                             # ! '3'
            self.charPressed.emit('3')

    def stop_monitoring(self):
        self.listener.stop()

    def start_monitoring(self):
        self.listener.start()
     
        
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()
 
        self.path = "images/"                # <---- установите свой путь к изображениям
        self.images = self.load_images(self.path)
        self.number_images = len(self.images)
        self.number_image = -1

        self.image_label = QLabel()
        self.image_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)              
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.image_label)  
        self.show()

        self.on_char_pressed('3')

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_char_pressed(self, char):
        if char == '0':
            if self.my_app.isVisible():
                self.my_app.hide()
            else:
                self.my_app.show()
        elif char == '2':
            self.number_image -= 1
            if self.number_image < 0:
                self.number_image = self.number_images - 1        
            pixmap = QPixmap(f"{self.path}{self.images[self.number_image]}")
            photoWidth = pixmap.width()
            photoHeight = pixmap.height()
            if photoWidth > 480 or photoHeight > 480:
                self.image_label.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(500, 500, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
            else:
                self.image_label.setPixmap(pixmap)   
        elif char == '3':
            self.number_image += 1
            if self.number_image == self.number_images:
                self.number_image = 0        
            pixmap = QPixmap(f"{self.path}{self.images[self.number_image]}")
            #print(f'{pixmap.width()} -- {pixmap.height()}') #
            photoWidth = pixmap.width()
            photoHeight = pixmap.height()
            if photoWidth > 480 or photoHeight > 480:
                self.image_label.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(500, 500, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
            else:
                self.image_label.setPixmap(pixmap)   # KeepAspectRatio QtImageViewer
        
    def load_images(self, path):
        # return array of images
        loadedImages = []
        folder_path = path
        # Получаем список файлов в папке
        files = listdir(folder_path)
        # Выводим имена файлов
        for file in files:
            loadedImages.append(file)
        return loadedImages        

    def init_ui(self):                                            # ?
        self.my_app = QWidget()                             
    
        self.my_app.setWindowTitle("Desktop application")
        self.my_app.setGeometry(1920 - 800, 50, 800, 250)         # ?

        # Название
        label_name = QLabel("Название:", self.my_app)
        label_name.setGeometry(20, 20, 155, 20)
        label_name.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        label_name_text = QLabel("Название", self.my_app)
        label_name_text.setGeometry(180, 20, 135, 20)
        label_name_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # Стоимость
        label_cost = QLabel("Стоимость:", self.my_app)
        label_cost.setGeometry(20, 50, 155, 20)
        label_cost.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        label_cost_text = QLabel("Стоимость", self.my_app)
        label_cost_text.setGeometry(180, 50, 135, 20)
        label_cost_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # Размер
        label_size = QLabel("Размер:", self.my_app)
        label_size.setGeometry(20, 80, 155, 20)
        label_size.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        label_size_text = QLabel("Размер", self.my_app)
        label_size_text.setGeometry(180, 80, 135, 20)
        label_size_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # Комплектация
        label_equipment = QLabel("Комплектация:", self.my_app)
        label_equipment.setGeometry(20, 110, 155, 20)
        label_equipment.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        label_equipment_text = QLabel("Комплектация", self.my_app)
        label_equipment_text.setGeometry(180, 110, 135, 20)
        label_equipment_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # Причина
        label_reason = QLabel("Причина:", self.my_app)
        label_reason.setGeometry(20, 140, 155, 20)
        label_reason.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        label_reason_text = QLabel("Причина", self.my_app)
        label_reason_text.setGeometry(180, 140, 135, 20)
        label_reason_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # Причина комментария
        label_reason_comment = QLabel("Причина комментария:", self.my_app)
        label_reason_comment.setGeometry(20, 170, 155, 20)
        label_reason_comment.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        label_reason_comment_text = QLabel("Комментарий", self.my_app)
        label_reason_comment_text.setGeometry(180, 170, 135, 20)
        label_reason_comment_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # Количество картинок
        label_image_count = QLabel("Количество картинок:", self.my_app)
        label_image_count.setGeometry(20, 200, 155, 20)
        label_image_count.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        label_image_count_text = QLabel("5", self.my_app)
        label_image_count_text.setGeometry(180, 200, 135, 20)
        label_image_count_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # Бренд
        label_brand = QLabel("Бренд:", self.my_app)
        label_brand.setGeometry(400, 20, 130, 20)
        label_brand.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        label_brand_text = QLabel("Бренд", self.my_app)
        label_brand_text.setGeometry(540, 20, 135, 20)
        label_brand_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # Подозрительный
        label_suspicious = QLabel("Подозрительный:", self.my_app)
        label_suspicious.setGeometry(400, 50, 130, 20)
        label_suspicious.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        label_suspicious_text = QLabel("Нет", self.my_app)
        label_suspicious_text.setGeometry(540, 50, 135, 20)
        label_suspicious_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        
        self.my_app.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(500, 500)

    monitor = KeyMonitor()
    monitor.charPressed.connect(window.on_char_pressed)
    monitor.start_monitoring()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здравствуйте, благодарю за ответ, у меня проблема была немного в другом, у меня PyQt5 и Threading конфликтовали между друг другом, в следствии получалось так, что когда я нажимал на клавишу которая создавала новое окно всё зависало, как я понял, один вечный цикл конфликтовал с другим, в следствии получаем то, что получили. В конечном итоге, я использовал pyqtSignal.

Comment: @DavidSevryukov нельзя взаимодействовать с виджетами в дополнительном потоке, это не безопасно. Сигналы и слоты - это то, что вам надо.